# Dynamically building queries in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a web page where users can see data from MongoDB on a map. I want to have several check boxes, radio buttons, etc to filter what is seen on the map. If I was using MySQL I would do

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = 1" 
if checkbox == "checked":
  query += "AND WHERE y = 2"
```

How can I replicate that with pymongo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply build up the query dict instead:

```
query = {'x': 1}
if checkbox == 'checked':
    query['y'] = 2

results = db.collection.find(query)
```

Doing an `OR` query would look like this:

```
query = [{'x': 1}]
if checkbox == 'checked':
    query.append({'y': 2})

results = db.collection.find({'$or': query})
```

Comment: And its even cleaner to build a mongo query dynamically than it is to build raw sql text (not talking about an ORM)

Comment: That worked like a charm! Now, what if I want to do OR instead of AND?

Comment: @user1084826: You should really [read the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/OR+operations+in+query+expressions). Its all right there on how to format queries.

Comment: @user1084826 Again, you've just got to build up the mongo query object. I updated the answer to give you an example.